# Adding tabs into Mozilla's Jetpack Panel module

Tags: tabs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Firefox extensions made in XUL had a nice Tab element. But with Jetpack, I see nothing that would allow me to make tabbed content in a panel module, for example.

I understand that Jetpack uses jQuery. Would the proper way to create tabs be to include jQuery UI or is there some other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Addon SDK encourages using standard web technologies instead of XUL, so the appropriate way is to use any JS framework; jQuery UI should be fine too.